# How to share AmazonSQS connection over multiple requests on tomcat?

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-sqs

I am building a live logging mechanism where one of the server will push the logging messages, to amazon SQS queue, and another server will pull the corresponding messages and show on a live monitoring website. Now I want to know on a tomcat server how can I share a sqs connection over multiple requests? Any ideas for connection pooling guys?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

AWS SQS provides a *stateless* RESTful API, which means that there is no such thing as "connection". You connect to it, send your request, get your response, and close HTTP session. There is nothing to share.

Comment: The _stateless_ nature of the service is actually great to share connections. As the server holds no state associated to the connection, once its used it is as good as a new one to be reused. So a connection pooling strategy should be good. It will reduce the overheads associated to the connection creation and overall latency.

Answer (score 2):

Using [AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/overview-summary.html) the class to access SQS is [AmazonSQSClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html). You can provide [AmazonSQSClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html) with [ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html) to setup the connection pool. By default [ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html) has a max connection pool size of 50 ([DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS)).